# What is the correct way to work with infinite dates (events that lasts forever) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, infinite

In my project I work with events, along with some data associated with them, each event has its `start_date` and `end_date`. Some events however last indefinitely and have `end_date` of `nil`, later user is able to set `end_date` to some real value, but meanwhile they should be treated like they never end.

I've found that it's very handy to work with periods like that using `Range`, so model looks like this:

```
class Event < ...
  # ...

  def period
    start_date .. (end_date || Date::Infinity.new)
  end
end
```

This code works well in most cases like:

```
period.include?(Time.zone.today)
# or
Time.zone.today > period.max
```

But `Date::Infinity` itself was made for internal use only. So I was wondering what are the best practices of working with infinite periods and is there are any libraries which can help with that?

Answer (score 0):

[The `Date` class is designed to be compared with numeric values](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E), including `Float::INFINITY` and `-Float::INFINITY`.

Comment: The problem with `Float::INFINITY` (and `Date::Infinity` too in that regard) is that you can't compare them to Dates, so this `Float::INFINITY > Time.zone.today` will fail as well as this `[Time.zone.today, Float::INFINITY].max` saying `ArgumentError: comparison of Float with Date failed` and I was hoping for more universal solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an infinite value because of recurrence, you may want to try one of the gems specifically made to handle event recurrence:

- Ice Cube (http://www.johncrepezzi.com/ice_cube/)
- Recurrence (https://github.com/fnando/recurrence)
- Schedule Fu (https://github.com/angelic/schedule_fu)

Comment: I'm working with historical events, so recurrance libraries wouldn't do much, but thanks for suggestion!